# How to replicate data from Parent to Child in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I want to modify CRM module in Odoo, so that customer can manage multiple lead in single form. For that I created a parent, child relationship. Both are in the same model **crm.model**

```
#Parent save id of child.
parent_id = fields.Many2one('crm.lead', string="Parent Lead", ondelete="cascade")
# Child save id of parent.
child_ids = fields.One2many('crm.lead', 'parent_id', string="Child Lead", ondelete="cascade" )
```

The form view is looking like this: [Form View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3gmL.png)

Now, I want to write code such that, whenever user enter data into the parent lead it will auto fill into the child lead.

So far, I have tried following:

1. Add onchange function, but is executing but doesn't updating the fields i child.

   ```
   @api.onchange('child_ids','net_net_all')
   def _update_values(self):
   detail = []
   if not self.parent_id:
       partner_probability = self.probability
       self.balance = self.net_net_all
       for record in self.child_ids:
           self.balance -= record.net_net_child_all
           detail.append((0,0,{
               'reference': self.reference,
               'partner_id': self.partner_id,
               'agency': self.agency,
               'partner_contact': self.partner_contact,
               'agency_contact': self.agency_contact,
               'agent_commission': self.agent_commission,
               'email_from': self.email_from,
               'phone': self.phone,
               'user_id': self.user_id,
               'team_id': self.team_id,
               'region': self.region,
               'segement': self.segement,
               'type_of_advertisement': self.type_of_advertisement,
               'planned_revenue_all': record.net_net_child_all * partner_probability,
               'planned_revenue': record.net_net_child * partner_probability,
               }))
       return {'value' : {'child_ids' : detail}}
   ```
2. Modifying **create** function but only effecting when the lead is created and not when the lead is modifying. Also, taking much time to execute properly.

   ```
   if len(vals) == 1 and 'message_follower_ids' in vals.keys():
       for record in self.child_ids:
           record.reference = self.reference
           record.partner_id = self.partner_id
           record.agency = self.agency
           record.partner_contact = self.partner_contact
           record.agency_contact = self.agency_contact
           record.agent_commission = self.agent_commission
           record.email_from = self.email_from
           record.phone = self.phone
           record.user_id = self.user_id
           record.team_id = self.team_id
           record.region = self.region
           record.segement = self.segement
           record.type_of_advertisement = self.type_of_advertisement
   ```

Please suggest a work around.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use the `related` attribute on your field? Odoo will do the lookup for you.

```
reference = fields.Char(related='parent_id.reference')
```

Check the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#related-fields) for more details.

Comment: I am using same model **crm.lead** and need to copy data on same field from parent to child.
For example: 
Data in user_id field in parent id should copy to user_id field in child_id.

Required for the purpose of reporting.

Comment: email_from = fields.Char('Email', related='parent_id.email_from', help="Email address of the contact person of Customer", index=True, track_visibility="onchange", store=True)

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: You would need to have one that is not related, so all parents would have `email_from` and the children would have `email_from_related` that relates to the normal `parent_id.email_from` to avoid recursion. Otherwise you have to make it a computed field with an `inverse` method which is probably more efficient, but slightly more complicated to set up.

Comment: isn't there is another way to work around ? Any python function or odoo api.

Comment: [link] (https://pastebin.com/YSgeJWM7)
But that didn't work, could you please rectify me.

Comment: You should try related field like tha answer of travisw. It should work for your case.